# JSdoc для расширения прототипа

Tags: ecmascript-6, модули, prototype, pixijs, jsdoc

Есть проект на js - ES6, классы, модульная архитектура (не typescript)
Все классы/методы описываются с помощью JSDoc для подсказок (VSCode)

Возникла проблема с расширением прототипа классов библиотеки PIXI
Частный пример: класс `PIXI.Text` наследуется от `PIXI.Sprite`, `PIXI.Sprite` наследуется от `PIXI.Container`

Необходим общий метод для всех этих классов, определяем через `prototype`:

```js
/**
 * @method
 * @name PIXI.Container#hide
 * @param {boolean} alpha
 */
PIXI.Container.prototype.hide = function(alpha = false){
    //...
}
```

При попытке использования метода `hide` у дочерних классов - не отображается подсказка (+ нельзя перейти к определению метода)

```js
let text = new PIXI.Text()
text.hide() // ничего не отображается
```

Подскажите пожалуйста правильный способ определения таких методов (в частности в модульной архитектуре)